# Visual studio 2012 is getting hanged while migration my project from 2010 to 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

My project is in visual studio 2010 and now I want it to migrate to 2012. when I open my project in 2012 I am able to build the solution. but when I am running it.

It starts use RAM more than 8 GB and system get hanged not able to open even task manager.

please help me what should I do to work my project in visual studio 2012.

My code in vb.net.

PS : using IIS
thanks in advace !!

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem like a problem of VS at all, the problem probably originates in your code somewhere, which *could* be caused by the upgrading mechanism. Without your code we can't really get a hang of what is going one. Although, you said the memory usage is maxing itself, this being said I'd advice you to download [dotMemory](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/). It'll help you find memory leaks and other related memory issues. It has a 5 day trial so if I were you I'd definitely check it out.

Comment: Use: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/Tutorial+1+-+Getting+Started+with+dotMemory and https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/Tutorial+2+-+How+to+Find+a+Memory+Leak+with+dotMemory